# How to use mapcar here?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

```
(defun find-attr (node attr)
    (let ((children (pt-children node)))
      (if (null children)
          nil
          (let ((subchildren (mapcar ##############

(get-value-if-attrib-present (node attrib) ...)
```

`pt` is a class. `(pt-children node)` yields children of `node` which are also `pt` objects. `attr` is a string. suppossing I write `get-value-if-attrib-present` to return the value of a `pt` object if it has the matching `attr`, how do i go about getting the list of all the values of subchildren of `node` with matching `attr` here (at ####....)?

Comment: omg, it doesnt work... hence here at SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Common Lisp use one of these functions:

- `REMOVE-IF`
- `REMOVE-IF-NOT`
- `REMOVE`

They go over a list and remove items. Keep those which you want.

Other wise `LOOP` will do it:

```
(LOOP for item in some-list
      when (predicate-p item)
      collect it)
```

`IT` is a `LOOP` feature -> it refers to the value returned by the predicate in the `WHEN` clause.

Comment: those remove functions are what I need!

Comment: I didn't know that loop had anaphors; that's a useful feature

Answer (score 1):

mapping approach:

```
;; assuming get-value-if-attrib-present simply returns nil when not present
;; (i.e. your attribute value cannot be nil without ambiguity)
;;
;; get the list of values from the children, matching attrib
;;
(mapcan (lambda (child)
          (if (get-value-if-attrib-present child attrib)
            (list child)))
        children)
```

`mapcan` expects the function to return lists, and it destructively catenates them. So you have to be careful not to return quoted lists from the lambda, or any lists that came from somewhere else (not consed up here).

In *Paradigms of Artificial Intelligence Programming* (a.k.a PAIP), Peter Norvig introduces a `mappend` function which does the same thing, but nondestructively. That's useful to have in your toolkit sometimes.