# Rewrite apply function to use recursion instead

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Probably the hardest part of learning lisp has been to think in the "lisp way" which is elegant and impressive, but not always easy. I know that recursion is used to solve a lot of problems, and I am working through a book that instead uses `apply` to solve a lot of problems, which I understand is not as lispy, and also not as portable.

An experienced lisper should be able to help with this logic without knowing specifically what `describe-path` `location` and `edges` refer to. Here is an example in a book I am working through:

```
(defun describe-paths (location edges)
  (apply (function append) (mapcar #'describe-path
               (cdr (assoc location edges)))))
```

I have successfully rewritten this to avoid `apply` and use recursion instead. It seems to be working:

```
(defun describe-paths-recursive (location edges)
  (labels ((processx-edge (edge)
         (if (null edge)
         nil
         (append (describe-path (first edge))
             (processx-edge (rest edge))))))
    (processx-edge (cdr (assoc location edges)))))
```

I would like some more seasoned pairs of eyes on this to advise if there is a more elegant way to translate the `apply` to recursion, or if I have done something unwise. This code seems decent, but would there been something even more "lispy" ?

Comment: If you want code reviews, there is http://codereview.stackexchange.com .
Stackoverflow is for actual practical problems.

Comment: More 'Lispy' would be to avoid stack overflows.

Comment: @RainerJoswig thanks, though I would consider this practical. Granted, I'm new to lisp and the culture in this lisp area of stackoverflow seems very different than other languages i've worked in on here. This would be a welcome question that receives a lot of answers in an area like C++

Comment: The original version is recursive. It calls itself in the call to MAPCAR.

Comment: @ThomasBartscher no it does not. look closely, the functions are different.

Comment: Oh, you're right. Damn plurals...

Comment: Crossposted to codereview as http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/36042/26855.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with this question; plenty of questions similar to this are asked in the python category, for example.

But to your question: what you are doing is Good. In fact, it closely resembles, nearly identically, a more general technique Peter Norvig shows in one of his Lisp books, so either you've read that book, or you stumbled upon a good practice on your own. Either way, this is a perfectly acceptable implementation of recursion.

Answer (score 6):

`(apply (function append) (mapcar #'g ...))` is just [`mapcan`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm) (**update:** [*with usual caveats*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20207041/why-does-this-mapcan-cause-my-repl-to-freeze) about destructive update and quoted lists, see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946612/how-to-use-mapcar-here/9949958#9949958)):

```
(defun describe-paths (location edges)
  (mapcan #'describe-path
               (cdr (assoc location edges))))
```

Recursion is good for thinking, for understanding. But actually using it in your code comes with a price.

Your recursive re-write is [tail recursive modulo cons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Tail_recursion_modulo_cons); no Lisp has this optimization AFAIK, even though [it was first described in 1974](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/cgi-bin/techreports/TRNNN.cgi?trnum=TR19), *in Lisp*.

So what you wrote is good as an *executable specification*.

But Common Lisp is a practical language. In particular, it has many ways to encode iteration. Remember, iterative processes are our goal; recursive processes are terrible, efficiency-wise. So when we write a code which is syntactically recursive, we still want it to describe an iterative process (such that runs in constant stack space).

Common Lisp, being a practical language, would have us just write the loop out directly. For one,

```
(defun describe-paths-loop (location edges &aux (res (list 1)) (p res))
  (dolist (x (cdr (assoc location edges)) 
             (cdr res))                   ; the return form
    (setf (cdr p) (describe-path x))
    (setf p (last p))))
```

is guaranteed to work in constant stack space.

<sup>**update:** this destructively concatenates lists returned by *`describe-path`* so it should take care not to return lists with the same `last` cons cell on separate invocations, or this could create circular structure. Alternatively, the call to `describe-path` could be wrapped in a `copy-list` call. Of course, if `describe-path` were to return a list which is already cyclic, `last` here would go into a loop too.</sup>

Comment: I'd be very surprised if it didn't, since it's an iteration construct, and the forms are executed in a tagbody, but I don't see where in [the documentation](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_dolist.htm) that `dolist` is _guaranteed_ to work in constant stack space.  For instance, [this](http://pastebin.com/b9BgL2A3) could be an implementation of `dolist` (I think), but it's still recursive and might not use constant stack space.

Comment: That possible caveat aside, +1 because this is the only answer that mentions the veritable `mapcan`!

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I always thought of `dolist` as a variant of `do` (just as `dotimes` too); and it does say "`do` *iterates*..." in the doc (just as it does for `dolist` itself). As for implementations, I'd code it with `PROG` and `go`, it feels like the most low-level to me. :) So yeah, maybe "guaranteed" was a bit of a wishful thinking... :)

Comment: That said, I'd file a bug report if I found an implementation that didn't make it an proper iteration construct.  (If it did TCO, it'd probably be OK.)

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor but TCO isn't guaranteed in CL. that much I do know. :)

Comment: Hence my "_if_ it did TCO".  I meant, _if_ the particular implementation guaranteed TCO on its `dolist ` implementation, I wouldn't file the bug report. :)

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor got it now. :) Why the TRMC isn't as widely popular as I'd like it to be, is still a mystery to me... OTOH if it were, I wouldn't have a chance to post this answer. :)

Comment: Fascinating, thanks. You threw me with the `&aux` I had to look that one up. I'm too used to `let*`

Comment: @OpenLearner [yes](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_dae.htm), and it doesn't even take one extra line of code. :)

Comment: I tested what you proposed at the beginning of this answer, and have opened a new question on it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20207041/why-does-this-mapcan-cause-my-repl-to-freeze

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor "Veritable" `mapcan`? Or "venerable"? :)

Comment: @Kaz hm… both really, I suppose :)

Answer (score 3):

I saw several opinions about using `apply` is a bad style. But actually that would be great if somebody will explain me why `apply` is considered to be bad.

What do you mean using a word "lispy". Common lisp allows to program in any style you want.

If "lispy" means functional programming style, then the first code is written in more functional programming style. A function is passed to a function `mapcar` and another function is passed to `apply` and all the job is done by passing the results of one function to another. In you code you don't pass functions as arguments to other functions. But recursion can be considered as functional programming style sign. And code in the book is shorter than yours.

If you don't like `apply` because of apply determines the argument count in runtime, you can use `reduce` in this situation (if I understood the data structures correctly):
(Thanks to Joshua Taylor for pointing a huge resource overhead without `:from-end t` key argument)

```
(defun describe-paths (location edges)
  (reduce #'append (mapcar #'describe-path
            (rest (assoc location edges))) :from-end t))
```

Anyway I'm pretty sure that the purpose of the code in the book is the education reason. It's an example of `mapcar` and `apply` that shows how lists are treated as data and code in lisp.

p.s. Actually I figured why `apply` can be bad (stack is used for function calls).

```
> (apply #'+ (make-list 500000 :initial-element 1))
*** - Lisp stack overflow. RESET
```

So as Rainer Joswig told it's lispy to avoid stack overflows. Reduce fix the problem.

```
> (reduce #'+ (make-list 50000000 :initial-element 1))
50000000
```

Comment: This is also a good method, thanks for mentioning it. Basically the problem with apply is that you will eventually hit the limit for call arguments. Recursion and use of reduce solve that problem.

Comment: @OpenLearner, recursion solve this problem only if tail call recursion optimization is available(or another similar optimization). Otherwise you are going to overflow your stack. You example doesn't have tail recursion optimization, so you are will overflow the stack with your implementation on big data.

Comment: @JustAnotherCurious not only TCO; it is often imperative to have [TRMCO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Tail_recursion_modulo_cons) which is non-existent AFAIK in Lisp. For instance, the OP's `describe-paths-recursive` is TRMC, so without that optimization it won't do us any good to code it in that way. :)

Comment: also, `apply` may have a limit on number of arguments. In some implementations, it can be in low hundreds I think. So for a list with 1000 elements or more, it would fail in such an implementation.

Comment: Yikes!  `(reduce 'append ...)`, if you're not using `:from-end t`, is _very_ inefficient, as it allocates and discards _lots_ of unnecessary memory.  `append` copies all but its first argument.  `(append (append (append x '()) y) z)` copies `x` three times, and copies `y` twice!  If you need to `(reduce 'append ...)`, be sure to `(reduce 'append ... :from-end)`, but also consider looking for alternatives (but `(reduce 'append ... :from-end t)` may be the appropriate solution in some cases).

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor You are 100% right. I'll edit my answer in case if someone won't read your comment.

Answer (score 3):

The Lisp way is to use functional, imperative or object-oriented programming (with or without mutable state) to solve a problem, or to invent some other programming as you see fit and express it in macros. Looking for recursion while ignoring other approaches is not the Lisp way; it's the way of the wayward Lisp academic.

The most straightforward way to rewrite the function:

```
(defun describe-paths (location edges)
  (apply (function append) (mapcar #'describe-path
               (cdr (assoc location edges)))))
```

is to use `loop`. The proper motivation for eliminting apply is that we expect many paths, which could exceed the limit on the number of arguments to a function.

All you are doing with `apply` is making a big argument list to the `append` function. We can append any number of lists into a big list with `loop` like this:

```
(defun describe-paths (location edges)
  (loop for path in (cdr (assoc location edges))
        appending (describe-path path))
```

Presumably, `describe-path` returns a list, and you want to catenate these together.

The `appending` clause of `loop`, which may also be spelled `append`, gathers appends the value of is argument form into an anonymous list. That list becomes the return value when the loop terminates.

We can use `nconcing` to improve the performance if we have justification in believing that the lists returned by `described-path` are freshly allocated on each call.

Comment: i have heard that `loop` is not the "lisp way" as many lisp purists stay away from `loop` since its structure is at great odds to the style of the rest of the language. but it's nice to see it as an example here.

Comment: can we be sure that `loop ... appending` is not quadratic in time? (unlike `nconcing`).

Comment: @WillNess The loop spec only says, "The append keyword causes its list values to be concatenated into a single list, as if they were arguments to the function append." You can `macroexpand` the loop for to see what is going on in your implementation. The difference between `nconc` and `append`, by the way, isn't time complexity. Naive accumulation with `nconc` is still quadratic, but reduces memory allocation. Reducing complexity requires maintaining a tail pointer to avoid repeatedly searching the accumulated list for the tail. This is independent of whether the inputs are copied or modified.

Comment: @Kaz right, just if we copy, we can't avoid the quadratic time, and if we don't, then we can, as you point out. Thanks. :) ... or maybe `append`'s implementation isn't trivial, under the hood.

Comment: @WillNess Copying the inputs doesn't require quadratic time. It is linear time. Note that `append` itself, when given all the pieces at once as arguments, can work in linear time, **and** it can use destructive manipulation internally to build up the list. I.e. it's not going to just call `reduce` over a binary-only version of `append`.  The difference between `nconc` or `append` is whether we copy the input lists to a new list structure with the same `car` fields, or whether we simply rewrite their tail `cdr`-s.

Comment: @Kaz (re: append) exactly what I was alluding to! :) But my argument was about the `loop` macro. It can't just call `append` with all these sub-lists as arguments; that would be equivalent to calling `(apply 'append ...)` with all its limitations. On the face of it, `loop` has only one possibility, and it is calling `reduce` with a binary constructor. It could of course be doing `(reduce #'(lambda(a b) (nconc (copy-list a) b)) ... :from-end t)`, or its equivalent.

Comment: @WillNess `loop` implementations typically generate a loop based on a `tagbody`. Accumulation is done with hidden variables that keep track of the tail pointer of the accumulated list. You can easily see what is going on by `macroexpand`-ing a loop form.

Comment: @Kaz I was suspecting as much (hence "its equivalent"). [Function calls are a glorified  `GOTO`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14316848/849891) anyway, aren't they?  :) So I guess we *can* safely expect reasonable performance for `LOOP`. Thanks!